# Comment with Auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, comments

I want the user to only  post a comment when logged in. Otherwise a massege appears 'You must be logged in to post a comment'. If I logged in it works if not it doesnt just redirect back!
**I solved it. The problem was that the PostCommentsController was in the admin middleware where you have to logged in to see If you are an admin. And if you not logged in redirect to index.**

the Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $data = [
            'post_id' => $request->post_id,
            'author' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'body' => $request->body
        ];
        
        Comment::create($data); 
        $request->session()->flash('comment_success','Your comment have been submited and is waiting moderation');
        return redirect()->back();
    } else {            
        $request->session()->flash('login','You must be logged in to post a comment');
        return redirect('/login')->back();
    }       
}
```

Comment: I just want to clarify, if the user is not logged in the user is redirected to login page right?

Comment: Yes I have plus ->back() in my else statement. So I changed  return redirect('/login'); But does not work. If I 'm not logged in redirect back to the index page where are several post.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) { 
        $request->session()->flash('login', 'You must be logged in to post a comment');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    $data = [
        'post_id' => $request->post_id,
        'author' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'body' => $request->body
    ];

    if (Comment::create($data)) {
        $request->session()->flash('comment_success', 'Your comment have been submitted and is waiting moderation');
        return redirect()->back(); 
    } 

    $request->session()->flash('comment_error', 'Your comment does not submited. Try again!!');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: where do you wont redirect??

Comment: see all available  methods  in [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirects)

Comment: It doesn't matter where I want to redirect(I tried /login,register). If I'm not logged in always redirect to the index page. And flash message does not appear either(You must be logged in to post a comment)

Comment: use [https://github.com/laracasts/flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) for easy way to show flesh message

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement, just use this code `return redirect('/login');` using `back()` function will redirect user back.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the built in Auth system, if you use that you can use constructors like the example from my project.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This just says that the user cannot access any of the methods in this class without being logged in. If they are not logged in it will redirect them back to the login page. You can also have, in your views, @auth and @guest. I use this to show info on private information e.g. private servers can only be seen by the logged in user.

If you have any other questions I may be able to answer, let me know, I would love to help!

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication